# How to get this flex layout without editing the HTML structure?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

This is the layout I'm trying to achieve with CSS:

[image]

And this is the HTML structure I have and can't touch at all, and what I've managed to add with CSS. It's close but something is missing:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item-1 {
  flex: 50%;
}

.item-2 {
  flex: 50%;
}

.item-3 {
  flex: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item-1">
    This is an image
  </div>
  <div class="item-2">
    This is a title
  </div>
  <div class="item-3">
    Short desc goes here.
  </div>
</div>
```

How do I fix this? Thank you!

Comment: You probably need grid rather than flexbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you're looking for a `grid` solution:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  /*two equal width columns.*/
  grid-template-rows: auto auto;
  /* two rows with auto height. */
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.item-1 {
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
}

.item-2 {
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
}

.item-3 {
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item-1">
    This is an image
  </div>
  <div class="item-2">
    This is a title
  </div>
  <div class="item-3">
    Short desc goes here.
  </div>
</div>
```